# System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name does not return my current domain user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use the following tag in my MVC view to display the current Windows user:

```
<label>@System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name</label>
```

but it displays :  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

Note that my user is registered on the domain, so I want it to display (DomainName\Username)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `User.Identity.Name`. `User` is a property in your controller class. In case you are using windows authentication it contains `WindowsPrincipal` object, and `Identity.Name` property contains name in format `DomainName\Username`

Comment: (User.Identity.Name) works if I use (Windows Authentication) which I am not.

Comment: actually, `WindowsIdentity` generated when you are using WinNT auth type. what auth type you are using?

Comment: I am using forms authentication. But I get it now, (WindowsIdentity) generated when using WinNT. Thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome. P.S. If you want to login your user from current domain 'using' windows system you have to use Windows Authentication. Forms Authentication is used when you are storing your users data in your persistence database.